# simple example for .blockUI in jquery

Tags: jquery, blockui

Please guide me to the purpose of blockUI with a simple demonstration.

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at the [demos on the plugin page](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos).

You need to do have the following in a page (in this order)

1. Add a reference to the [jQuery core](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.min.js&downloadBtn=) script
2. Add a reference to the [Block UI script](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#download)
3. Add the jQuery code required to achieve the overlay when it is required

Answer (score 2):

To create a js file [jquery.blockUI.js](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js) from this link.and put it into your project where the js files inclu

and in html write this code:

```
    <div id="throbber" style="display:none;">
        <img src="/static/image/gears.gif" /><h4>Please..</h4>
    </div>
    {% block customjs %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message:$('#throbber') }); 
       });
    </script>
```

This is a simple demonstration.May be it will be helps to you

Add a reference to the [jquery.blockUI.js](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#demo10').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ 
            message: '<h1>Auto-Unblock!</h1>', 
            timeout: 2000 
        }); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just got help from Adrian Brand and made it work...
So if anyone else is looking for a working sample:

```js
function block() {
  $.blockUI();
  setTimeout(unBlock, 5000); 
}

function unBlock() {
  $.unblockUI();
}

function alertUser() {  
  alert('Alert User'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

<button onclick="alertUser()">Alert</button>
<button onclick="block()">Block!</button>
<button onclick="unBlock()">UnBlock!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [homepage](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/):

> The jQuery BlockUI Plugin lets you
>   simulate synchronous behavior when
>   using AJAX, without locking the
>   browser[1](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/). When activated, it will
>   prevent user activity with the page
>   (or part of the page) until it is
>   deactivated. BlockUI adds elements to
>   the DOM  to give it both the
>   appearance and behavior of blocking
>   user interaction.

If you want to have ajax, but you also want to block user input while a long ajax request is happening, then BlockUI is for you.

Comment: Hi i would like to simple demonstation from you people since i am new to JQuery it woulld be more helpful to me.

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jquery BlockUi Plugin</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn">
        Click me to block UI
    </button>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn').click(function(argument) {
        $.blockUI({message:"Ui is blocked"});
        setTimeout($.unblockUI,2000)
    })
</script>

</html>
```