# How do I disable a page after a submit?

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net

I am looking for a way to prevent multiple submits on a page.  I have a table that is displayed on a submit or href click in jquery.  How do I have everything behind the table grey opacity and disabled?

```
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <input class="reloadPage" type="button"/>
    ...
    <div id="divLoad" style="display:none;">
        <table id="tblLoading">...</table>
    </div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".reloadPage").click(function () {
    $("#divLoad").show();
    //grey backdrop and disable page
    ....
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery block ui [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

Comment: I have jquery-1.4.1.js and no luck on the addition.  blockUI() Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: did u include all files, look the instruction in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624699/simple-example-for-blockui-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

or simplemodal: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Answer (score 0):

To do it manually you could try the following.

Add this style

```
#block
{
   background-color:#000;
   opacity:0.5;
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   top:0px;
}
```

Then this code should black out the screen.

```
$("body").append("<div id='block'></div>");
```

To remove it call:

```
$("#block").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the filter:alpha(opacity = 0); opacity:0.0; style.